# Page refreshing hundreds of times

Tags: php, email, refresh

I have some code I'm implementing that was written by someone else (yes, with their permission).  It basically sends out an email every "x" seconds where you can set "x" so that you don't go over an hourly email limit set by your webhost.  It will send an email, then wait "x" seconds, refresh the page, send an email, wait "x" seconds, refresh the page, send an email, etc.

**My question:** If I'm sending like 2,000 emails via this method, are there any downsides to refreshing a page this many times?  Or would it be better to modify the script to send 100 emails at a time, then refresh, send 100 more, etc.?

Comment: Why don't you just use [`sleep()`](http://php.net/sleep)

Comment: Why don't you just use a cron job, instead of refreshing the page?

Comment: oh boy, i know you have pacience!

Comment: @SableFoste Good suggestion, if the webhoster allows it. Not many do.

Comment: Yes it would be better to use a cron job for that.

Comment: @ Sable and Niloy: This is an OsCommerce user-created mod and I'm not inclined to fiddle with it too much (by incorporating cron, for instance) as I don't want to break something.  Is there anything wrong with refreshing a page this many times concurrently?

@ Nile: That would cause a script to be running for hrs.  This equals unhappy webhost.

@ Twisted1919: The page automatically refreshes.